# How to display values in OCaml Playground

Tags: ocaml

In the OCaml repl if I run multiple phrases it will print the value of each.

```ml
# let add x y = x + y;;
val add : int -> int -> int = <fun>
# add 5 6;;
- : int = 11
```

However in [the OCaml Playground](https://ocaml.org/play) it only prints the first one:

```ml
val add : int -> int -> int = <fun>
```

Why is that? Can I make it print everything?

Comment: If I enter `let add x y = x + y;;` and `add 1 2;;` and run, I see `val add : int -> int -> int = <fun>` and `- : int = 3` in the output, so I'm going to have to say I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Of course, you wouldn't expect to see anything about `add` if you tried: `let add x y = x + y in add 5 6;;`

Comment: When I try the playground on Mac (Safari and Chrome) it shows syntax errors no matter what I type in, including blank lines. So I can't try anything. Maybe your best bet is to install OCaml on your own system?

Comment: I got similar results to Jeffrey's on Mac just now. Second the suggestion to install it locally. And try out utop vs the standard toplevel.

Comment: @Chris: I don't, as I stated in the question. That's weird. What browser are you using?

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I do have it installed on my system. That doesn't mean the playground isn't useful too.

Comment: @Chris: I just tried again in Firefox and Chrome Incognito. It definitely only prints the `val` line.

Comment: It worked as you are expecting in Chrome on Windows 11.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot because I've tried Chrome on Windows 10 and I would be *very* surprised if it's the Windows version that makes the difference...

Answer (score 0):

Ah I figured it out. You need a newline after the last `;;` otherwise it ignores it.